# How to sum row values by background color

Tags: c#, datagridview

In each row the cells are highlighted by background color (three names per line). I want the sum of the values by the background color (not the cell contents). Even after various attempts I have to admit that I have no idea how to fill the `ListBox` with  names (Teacher, Students) and the sum  of each line into the `ListBox` (see the following code…) If the sum is 3, then the entry in the `ListBox` should be displayed with the corresponding name. 
The result in the `ListBox` should look  as shown below:

```
3; Teacher
3; Students
```

```
int sum = 0; 
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
   {
      sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Style.BackColor == Color.YellowGreen);

      if (sum == 3)
      {
         sum++;
         listBox9.Items.Add(sum);
         listBox9.ForeColor = Color.DarkCyan;
         listBox9.Font = new Font("Georgia", 16);
```

[image: DGV with 3 Cells highlighted per row and a ListBox]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, "OhBeWise"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you asked for. For each row, it counts all cells with a background color of YellowGreen and associates the row name (i.e. the name in your example is "teachers" and "students" as indicated in the column with title "DD").

```
// Setup the DataGridView as in your example
var dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Columns.Add("s1", "s1");
dgv.Columns.Add("s2", "s2");
dgv.Columns.Add("s3", "s3");
dgv.Columns.Add("s4", "s4");
dgv.Columns.Add("s5", "s5");
dgv.Columns.Add("s6", "s6");
dgv.Columns.Add("DD", "DD");    
dgv.Rows.Add("Fiona", "Lila", "Ben", "Ella", "Leon", "John", "Teachers");
dgv.Rows.Add("Jack", "Luke", "Fiona", "Sophie", "Lila", "Leon", "Students");
dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[0].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[1].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[1].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
dgv.Rows[1].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;

// Query the DataGridView, counting each row's cells with the YellowGreen background color, correlating with the row name stored in the DD column
var sums = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => new { 
        Name = row.Cells[row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().First(cell => cell.OwningColumn.HeaderText == "DD").ColumnIndex].Value , 
        Count = row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Count(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.YellowGreen)})
    .ToList();

// Add the counts for each row to the ListView
var lb = new ListBox();
sums.ForEach(s => lb.Items.Add($"{s.Name}: {s.Count}"));
```

Comment: thank you very much for all the effort and the excellent example!! the code is executed! is it practically possible to display only the teachers  or  the students in the listbox? (both names and counters should not be displayed ) 
the result in the listbox should look as shown below
3; Teachers 
 or  
3; students.  
thank you very much "Carlo Bos"!!!